# How to combine the vertical scroll of two vuetify data tables?

Tags: javascript, datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have been trying so many different solutions to this problem and have not come close. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to combine the vertical scroll of three datatables so that if you scroll on any of them they all scroll vertically.

```
    var scrollers = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-together");
    var scrollersTo = Array.from(scrollers);
    scrollersTo.find(function (element){
      return element.childNodes[1];
    })  
      console.log("scrollersTo", scrollersTo)
    var scrollerDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(
      scrollers,
      function (testElement) {
        return testElement.nodeName === "DIV";
      },
      console.log("scroller", scrollers),
      console.log("scroller divs", scrollerDivs)
    );
    scrollerDivs.forEach(function (element) {
      element.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
        scrollAll(e.target.scrollTop, scrollerDivs);
      });
    });
```

in mounted - above I was trying to access the element and which worked, but it seems like I need to navigate further down in the element into a childNode and nodeName (two different methods) of index 1. This however never would only ever return undefined no matter which method I used.

```
scrollAll(scrollTop, scrollerDivs) {
  scrollerDivs.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log("scrollALL", scrollTop);
    element.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  });
}
```

Above is the function that should invoke the scrolling in methods

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headersSelected"
    :items="items"
    hide-default-footer
    fixed-header
    id="optionChainTable"
    v-scroll#optionChainTable="scrollOptionChain"
    :items-per-page="listLength"
    v-sortable-table="{ onEnd: sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey }"
    :key="anIncreasingNumber"
    item-key="key"
    disable-sort
    disable-filtering
    disable-pagination
    class="scroll-together"
  >
    <!-- v-scroll.self="onScroll" -->
    <!-- :loading="isLoading"
     -->
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat dense>
        <template v-if="header == 'Call'">
          <v-tooltip right>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                icon
                text
                small
                @click.stop="headersSelectorDialog = true"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-table-headers-eye</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span class="tooltip">Select Headers</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="headersSelectorDialog"
            scrollable
            max-width="250px"
          >
            <v-card>
              <v-system-bar color="primary darken-2" dark>
                <span class="text-caption">Select Headers</span>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-icon @click="headersSelectorDialog = false">
                  mdi-close
                </v-icon>
              </v-system-bar>
              <v-card-text style="height: 400px">
                <v-checkbox
                  dense
                  v-for="header in headersList"
                  :key="header.value"
                  :label="header.text"
                  hide-details
                  v-model="header.selectable"
                  @click="selectHeader(header)"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </template>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-title>{{ header }}</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <template v-if="header == 'Put'">
          <v-tooltip right>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                icon
                text
                small
                @click.stop="headersSelectorDialog = true"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-table-headers-eye</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span class="tooltip">Select Headers</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="headersSelectorDialog"
            scrollable
            max-width="250px"
          >
            <v-card>
              <v-system-bar color="primary darken-2" dark>
                <span class="text-caption">Select Headers</span>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-icon @click="headersSelectorDialog = false">
                  mdi-close
                </v-icon>
              </v-system-bar>
              <v-card-text style="height: 400px">
                <v-checkbox
                  dense
                  v-for="header in headersList"
                  :key="header.value"
                  :label="header.text"
                  hide-details
                  v-model="header.selectable"
                  @click="selectHeader(header)"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </template>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you share the whole component? You should be able to do that with native Vuejs stack, without using Javascript native methods.

Comment: I edited and added the child component above @jssDev

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Vuetify `v-scroll` and target the div/table by using its id, see here [scroll target](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/scroll/#target).

Here is the working example, from where you can get the idea. **FOR A BETTER VIEW SEE ON FULL SCREEN**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
           { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0, iron: '1%', },
    { name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9.0, carbs: 37, protein: 4.3, iron: '1%', },
    { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16.0, carbs: 23, protein: 6.0, iron: '7%', },
    { name: 'Cupcake', calories: 305, fat: 3.7, carbs: 67, protein: 4.3, iron: '8%', },
    { name: 'Gingerbread', calories: 356, fat: 16.0, carbs: 49, protein: 3.9, iron: '16%', },
    { name: 'Jelly bean', calories: 375, fat: 0.0, carbs: 94, protein: 0.0, iron: '0%', },
    { name: 'Lollipop', calories: 392, fat: 0.2, carbs: 98, protein: 0, iron: '2%', },
    { name: 'Honeycomb', calories: 408, fat: 3.2, carbs: 87, protein: 6.5, iron: '45%', },
    { name: 'Donut', calories: 452, fat: 25.0, carbs: 51, protein: 4.9, iron: '22%', },
    { name: 'KitKat', calories: 518, fat: 26.0, carbs: 65, protein: 7, iron: '6%', },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    scrollTable1() {
      const table1 = this.$el.querySelector('#table1');
      const table2 = this.$el.querySelector('#table2');
      table2.scrollTop = table1.scrollTop;
    },
    scrollTable2() {
      const table1 = this.$el.querySelector('#table1');
      const table2 = this.$el.querySelector('#table2');
      table1.scrollTop = table2.scrollTop;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#table1 {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#table2 {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-data-table
        id="table1"
        v-scroll:#table1="scrollTable1"
        dense :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-key="name"
        disable-pagination
        hide-default-footer

      ></v-data-table>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
      <v-data-table
        id="table2"
        v-scroll:#table2="scrollTable2"
        dense :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-key="name"
        disable-pagination
        hide-default-footer

      ></v-data-table>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>

</v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. the child component is the data table and this is being created twice on the parent component for as two different tables.

Comment: <table  :items="simPut" header="Put" /> <table :items="simCall" header="Call" /> are the two components on the parent, so they are created based on if statements from the same child component. This causes the child component to only have one v-data-table. Maybe I need a way to change the id based on which it is and emit it to the parent.

Comment: Well it depends on your requirement, your question was "How to combine the vertical scroll of two vuetify data tables?" according to this the base idea is above